# VBA code in Access to create Excel file with several conditional formatting rules from query export

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have been utilizing some of the other questions on here to try to piece together my code for this particular function.  It has resulted in this:

```
Private Sub btnExportComparisonResult_Click()
Dim xlapp As New Excel.Application
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim rng As Object
    
    
DoCmd.Hourglass True
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

kitnum1 = fncGetViewingNum1()
kitnum2 = fncGetViewingNum2()

    DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM temp_COMPARE "
    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO temp_COMPARE ( Type, COMPARE1_OSPN, COMPARE1_Quantity, COMPARE1_Desc, COMPARE2_OSPN, COMPARE2_Quantity, COMPARE2_Desc ) " _
                & "SELECT '1' AS Type, COMPARE1.OSPN, COMPARE1.Quantity, COMPARE1.Desc, COMPARE2.OSPN, COMPARE2.Quantity, COMPARE2.Desc " _
                & "FROM COMPARE1 INNER JOIN COMPARE2 ON (COMPARE1.Quantity = COMPARE2.Quantity) AND (COMPARE1.OSPN = COMPARE2.OSPN) " _
                & "ORDER BY COMPARE1.OSPN; "
    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO temp_COMPARE ( Type, COMPARE1_OSPN, COMPARE1_Quantity, COMPARE1_Desc, COMPARE2_OSPN, COMPARE2_Quantity, COMPARE2_Desc ) " _
                & "SELECT '2' AS Type, COMPARE1.OSPN, COMPARE1.Quantity, COMPARE1.Desc, COMPARE2.OSPN, COMPARE2.Quantity, COMPARE2.Desc " _
                & "FROM COMPARE1 INNER JOIN COMPARE2 ON COMPARE1.OSPN = COMPARE2.OSPN " _
                & "WHERE (((COMPARE1.Quantity) <> [COMPARE2].[Quantity])) " _
                & "ORDER BY COMPARE1.OSPN; "
    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO temp_COMPARE ( Type, COMPARE1_OSPN, COMPARE1_Quantity, COMPARE1_Desc, COMPARE2_OSPN, COMPARE2_Quantity, COMPARE2_Desc ) " _
                & "SELECT '3' AS Type, COMPARE1.OSPN, COMPARE1.Quantity, COMPARE1.Desc, COMPARE2.OSPN, COMPARE2.Quantity, COMPARE2.Desc " _
                & "FROM COMPARE1 LEFT JOIN COMPARE2 ON COMPARE1.OSPN = COMPARE2.OSPN " _
                & "WHERE (((COMPARE2.OSPN) Is Null)); "
    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO temp_COMPARE ( Type, COMPARE1_OSPN, COMPARE1_Quantity, COMPARE1_Desc, COMPARE2_OSPN, COMPARE2_Quantity, COMPARE2_Desc ) " _
                & "SELECT '4' AS Type, COMPARE1.OSPN, COMPARE1.Quantity, COMPARE1.Desc, COMPARE2.OSPN, COMPARE2.Quantity, COMPARE2.Desc " _
                & "FROM COMPARE1 RIGHT JOIN COMPARE2 ON COMPARE1.OSPN = COMPARE2.OSPN " _
                & "WHERE (((COMPARE1.OSPN) Is Null)); "

        strFolder = Environ("HOMEDRIVE") & Environ("HOMEPATH") & "\Downloads"
        strFileDate = Format(DatePart("m", Date), "00") & "." & Format(DatePart("d", Date), "00") & "." & Right(DatePart("yyyy", Date), 2)
        strFile = "Compare Kits " & kitnum1 & " & " & kitnum2 & " - " & strFileDate & ".xlsx"
            
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, 10, "qryExportCOMPARE", strFolder & "\" & strFile, , "Compare"
        
        StartTime = DateAdd("s", 2, Now())
            Do While Now() < StartTime
                DoEvents
            Loop
        
        Set xlsobj = CreateObject("excel.application")

        Set wb = xlsobj.Workbooks.Open(strFolder & "\" & strFile)
                            
            With wb.Worksheets("Compare")
                .Columns("A:Z").AutoFit
                
                .Rows("1:1").Font.Bold = True
                
                .Columns("A:A").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
                
                .Range("$D:$F").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlUp
                
                With .Range("$B:$B,$E:$E")
                    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$B1<>$E1"
                    .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
                    With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
                        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                        .Color = 65535
                        .TintAndShade = 0
                    End With
                End With
                
                With .Range("$A:$F")
                    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$A1<>$D1"
                    .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
                    With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
                        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                        .Color = 65535
                        .TintAndShade = 0
                    End With
                End With
                
                With .Range("$A:$F")
                    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=ISBLANK(A1)=TRUE"
                    .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
                    .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = True
                End With
                
                With .Range("1:1")
                    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=""text"">1000000=TRUE"
                    .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
                    .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = True
                End With
            End With
                
            xlsobj.ActiveWorkbook.Save
                            
            xlsobj.Quit
        
        StartTime = DateAdd("s", 2, Now())
            Do While Now() < StartTime
                DoEvents
            Loop
            
        Application.FollowHyperlink strFolder & "\" & strFile
                                        
            Set xlsobj = Nothing
            Set wb = Nothing
            Set sheet = Nothing
            
DoCmd.Hourglass False
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
            
 End Sub
```

Now I am receiving a 1004 error when using the "with" statements for my ranges.  I would appreciate any help to push me in the right direction for getting the code to work as intended with several conditional formatting rules as I'm not sure how to best implement the code from Excel's macro recorder.

Thanks!

Comment: I do not get this error with my code which is essentially the same for setting conditional formatting. Exactly which line throws error? Could it be the line that compares a string with a number?

Comment: The error shows up on the conditional formatting at “ With .Range("$B:$B,$E,$E")”.  There’s no comparing a string to a number. The SQL queries look for differences in the values of multiple fields, which are set up in pairs. The data is comparing two itemized orders. But I’m not having any errors on that part of the code and it currently creates an excel file like it should. The formatting and conditional formatting rules are the only thing that’s not being applied correctly to that Excel file for some reason.

Comment: Ran through the code again and it looks like it is working.  I may have had an old instance of Excel running, which I have noticed affects how the code functions significantly.  Provided code has been updated to what ended up working for me.